# Least distance of a particle under central force

Tags: classical-mechanics, celestial-mechanics

A particle starts at great distance with velocity V. Let p be length of perpendicular from the center of a star on the tangent to the initial path of particle. Show that the least distance of the path of particle from the center of the star is $\lambda$ where

$$\ V^2\lambda = \sqrt{\mu^2 + p^2V^4}-\mu$$
Where $\mu$ is a constant.

Solution:

I have begun by taking central acceleration $P$ = -$\mu/r^2$ and arrived  at the result that $v^2 = h^2/p^2 = 2\mu/r + C$, where $C$ is the constant of integration. At a large distance, i.e. , at infinity $v = V$, hence I arrived at the result that $v^2 = h^2/p^2 = 2\mu/r + V^2$. However I am unable to proceed any further. Can anyone please help?

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64079528, this should be about the same situation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Hamiltonian and energy of the particle is $E=H({\bf x},\dot {\bf x})=\frac{m}2|\dot {\bf x}|^2-\frac{m\mu}{|{\bf x}|}$, giving the second order equation of motion $\ddot {\bf x}=-\frac{\mu {\bf x}}{|{\bf x}|^3}$. By the initial conditions, $E=\frac{m}{2}V^2$.

Writing the equation in polar coordinates results in $L=r^2\dot\phi$ as the constant angular momentum and
$$
E=\frac{m}2[\dot r^2+r^2\dot\phi^2]-\frac{m\mu}{r}
\\~\\
V^2=\dot r^2+\frac{L^2}{r^2}-\frac{2\mu}{r}
$$
At the point $r=  λ$ of closest approach we have $\dot r=0$. So it only remains to determine $L$ in the above equation. For large $r$ the trajectory is, selecting an approach from above, ${\bf x}=(x,y)=(p,y_0-Vt)$, so that $L=r^2\dot\phi=x\dot y-\dot xy=-pV$. Thus the equation for $r=  λ$ is
$$
V^2λ^2+2\muλ=p^2V^2,
\\~\\
(V^2λ+μ)^2=p^2V^4+μ^2.
$$

---

**Polar coordinates:** The polar coordinates ${\bf x}=r{\bf s}$ give $\dot {\bf x}=\dot r{\bf s}+r\dot {\bf s}$, with $\dot {\bf s}=\omega R{\bf s}$, $ω$ the angular velocity and $R$ a rotation by $90°$, $R^2=-I$. Then
\begin{align}
\ddot {\bf x}&=\ddot r{\bf s}+2\dot r\dot {\bf s}+r\ddot {\bf s}\\
&=\ddot r{\bf s}+2\dot r\omega R{\bf s}+r[\dot ωR{\bf s}-ω^2{\bf s}]\\
&=-\frac{\mu{\bf s}}{r^2}
\end{align}
Comparing components gives
\begin{align}
2\dot rω+r\dot ω&=0&\implies L&=r^2ω\\
\ddot r-rω^2&=-\frac{\mu}{r^2}&\implies 2E&=\dot r^2+\frac{L^2}{r^2}-\frac{2\mu}r
\end{align}
with constants $L$ and $E$.

Comment: I did not understand the trajectory part. How do we get values of (x,y)?

Comment: That was not really that important. The important facts are that per the description of the asymptotics the particle at infinity moves on the line $x=p$ with velocity $\dot y=-V$, $\dot x=0$. Then compute $L$ as the third component of $\bf x\times \dot{\bf x}$, sign is not that important as only $L^2$ is used.

Comment: Thank you. But why is $L=r^2\dot\phi=x\dot y-\dot xy$ and why is$ \dot y=-V$ ?

Comment: Taking $H=E$ as Hamiltonian function in the polar coordinates, the impulse for the angle is $p_\phi=\partial_{\dot\phi}H=mr^2\dot\phi$, and as $\partial_\phi H=0$, this angle impulse or angular momentum is constant.

Comment: At infinity why is there no velocity component in x direction?

Comment: Because I chose the y-axis to be parallel to the tangent at "infinity".

Answer (score 0):

You have to make $3$ observations:

1. At the point of minimum distance, you need velocity of approach to be $0$. Hence, the velocity would be perpendicular to the line joining centre to particle.
2. Angular momentum is conserved here from centre of the star, because torque of a central force about the centre is $0$.
3. This would be the equation of energy conservation.

Do these three things, and you'll get your result.

Comment: The velocity is not $0$, but the component of velocity along line joining centre to particle is zero. If it were not, $\frac {dr}{dt}$ won't be zero, but it has to be since $r$ is minimum

Comment: I am still unable to get the desired result